# How to store user information with Net Core API with external users from Auth0

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, auth0

I am building an API which will use authentication with Auth0 and will have web and mobile clients.

Both clients will get their tokens using web based login from Auth0.

I am looking for the best way to get and store some user information in my API database, so I can e.g. list users in some group, relate article with the author, give some permissions to the user which cannot be stored in Auth0 (for 2 reasons: no mtm tokens and more important, that it's sort of multi tenant app and permissions are to complex to keep them in tokens).

There is userId in the token which can be used but e.g. when to trigger user save/update? Running it on each and every request does not sound efficient.

Anyone has done something like this?

How to approach it in the best way?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you're trying to achieve, but you could subscribe to post-registration hooks on Auth0 https://auth0.com/docs/hooks/concepts/post-user-registration-extensibility-point and then create the user in your database. I imagine you will not be using Auth0 for authorization then, only authentication?

Comment: indeed. My authorizing is to complex to do that with Auth0

Comment: So storing users with domain-specific metadata in your database would suffice? Sorry I don't understand what the problem is..

Comment: You're looking for "user account provisioning": on sign-in, you lookup the identity in your local DB using the UPN from the provider. You can keep the external token or release a new 'local' token to the client. If a user-account doesn't exist: create one, if it exists, update it. When calling `AddOpenIdConnect`, pass options with a callback for [Event.OnTokenValidated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectevents.ontokenvalidated) where you can do the provisioning and optionally transform the AuthenticationTicket.

Comment: is it called when user just calling an API with token? because API is not involved in any way in sign in process.

Comment: so far my only one idea is to use "Rules" and call server endpoint when user logs in with Auth0 and send the user data, so then I can check if user is registered with the API or not. Sounds quite good to me to be honest but I am still interested if there's better solution

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out a solution, however if anyone here would recommend a better approach, please do! Thanks to comments I went into hooks and then rules direction, so I appreciate any engagement.

I see it as fairly simple case, a bit tricky during local development but can be worked around with some development middleware in the API.

I am going to use Auth0 rules with crazy simple rule:

```js
function (user, context, callback) {
  const axios = require('axios');
    axios.post('https://my-web-api.com/auth0/notify', { user }, {
  headers: {
  'x-api-key': configuration.API_KEY
  }})
  .then(() => callback(null, user, context));
}
```

In the Rules, I have added `API_KEY` as a variable so it is not there in the code, encrypted, safe.

By using this I will send the current user profile from Auth0 to the backend where I will simply check if the user exists or not and update a profile if necessary.

As per [docs](https://auth0.com/docs/rules):

> Please note that rules also run during the token refresh flow.

it gives me also updates during the refreshing flow, so if anything changes, I will get the updates as well.